# Dynamic Data Masking Doesn't Seem To Work Correctly With ISNULL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, data-masking, dynamic-data-masking

Here is the code to reproduce the issue:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDataMasking](
    [RowId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId] [int] NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(2, "XXXX", 2)') NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(2, "XXXX", 2)') NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeDataMasking] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RowId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Insert Into dbo.EmployeeDataMasking (EmployeeId, LastName, FirstName)
VALUES( 1,'Smithsonian','Daniel'),( 2,'Templeton','Ronald')

-- Partial data masking works correctly here
Select  
    EmployeeId,
    LastName,
    FirstName
From dbo.EmployeeDataMasking

-- Partial data masking does not work correctly here. Full masking is used.
Select  
    EmployeeId,
    ISNULL(LastName,'') as LastName,
    ISNULL(FirstName,'') as FirstName
From dbo.EmployeeDataMasking
```

[image]

It appears, when using ISNULL, the partial masking is being converted to a full (default) mask. Is this the expected behavior?

Update: I discovered that COALESCE does not exhibit this problem. These queries return the expected results:

```
Select  
    EmployeeId,
    COALESCE(LastName,'') as LastName,
    COALESCE(FirstName,'') as FirstName
From dbo.EmployeeDataMasking
```

Using Azure SQL Database

Answer (score 2):

As a test, I created a custom user function that does nothing except pass the string back to the caller; it also exhibits this behavior.

Be aware, this code will drop users and objects, so only run it in a test database.

First, we create the required objects, users, and insert some data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.EmployeeDataMasking', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.EmployeeDataMasking;
END
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.SomeFunc', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.SomeFunc;
END
GO

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.database_principals dp
    WHERE dp.name = N'SomeUser'
    )
BEGIN
    DROP USER [SomeUser];
END
CREATE USER [SomeUser] WITHOUT LOGIN;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [SomeUser];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDataMasking](
    [RowId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId] [int] NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(2, "XXXX", 2)') NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(2, "XXXX", 2)') NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeDataMasking] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RowId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SomeFunc(@i varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @i;
END
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON dbo.SomeFunc TO [SOmeUser];
GRANT EXECUTE TO [SomeUser];
GRANT SHOWPLAN TO [SomeUser];


Insert Into dbo.EmployeeDataMasking (EmployeeId, LastName, FirstName)
VALUES( 1,'Smithsonian','Daniel'),( 2,'Templeton','Ronald')
```

Next, we'll query the data from the perspective of the non-privileged user:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = N'SomeUser';
Select  
    EmployeeId,
    ISNULL(LastName,'') as LastName,
    ISNULL(FirstName,'') as FirstName,
    dbo.SomeFunc(LastName) as LastName,
    dbo.SomeFunc(FirstName) as FirstName,
    COALESCE(LastName,'') as LastName,
    COALESCE(FirstName,'') as FirstName
FROM dbo.EmployeeDataMasking
REVERT
```

The results:

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║ EmployeeId ║ LastName ║ FirstName ║ LastName ║ FirstName ║ LastName ║ FirstName ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║          1 ║ xxxx     ║ xxxx      ║ xxxx     ║ xxxx      ║ SmXXXXan ║ DaXXXXel  ║
║          2 ║ xxxx     ║ xxxx      ║ xxxx     ║ xxxx      ║ TeXXXXon ║ RoXXXXld  ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝
```

As you can see, the custom user function, `dbo.SomeFunc` exhibits the same behavior as `ISNULL`.  At this point, I'm unsure why, since `COALESCE` does not exhibit the unwanted behavior.